# Unable to add repositories to the Rancher

Tags: kubernetes, rancher-rke

I am facing issue while adding any of the nexus related repositories to the rke rancher. I am getting the error as shown below while I was trying to add the helm chart repository to the rancher. The version of rancher I am using is 2.6.x.
[secrets not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vI3FI.png)

The same helm repository I am able to add in any of the other rancher.